# Ccreate an .exe from a .C file on Windows

Tags: c, windows, compiler-construction, exe

I would like to know if it is possible to create a .EXE from a .C file without using any compiler on Windows ?

Comment: Weird question. Can you tell us what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I've seen this question on SO before - I'm guessing it's a homework problem or interview question ?

Comment: @Cody in morning my friend called me and asked he needs to creates exe files from a .C file ,i told him to just run it using compiler and exe will automatically be created but he want not to use any of compiler and googled for it but couldn't find anything .....

Comment: This is the entire point of a compiler. What problem is your *friend* trying to solve? Why does he not want to use a compiler? Is he also opposed to using keyboards and monitors?

Comment: The thing is he could not find Bin folder on his machine where these are getting generated but @Cody there are some appication like

Comment: Gentee that helps in generating exe files can not we use it to create file from C programme

Comment: @AMIT: Gentee is a programming language. It has a syntax that's *based* on C, but it doesn't have anything to do with C. And it *also* has to be compiled into an executable. Same as C and all other compiled languages. The other option is an interpreted language, but that also has nothing to do with C.

Comment: Thansk @Cody for your explanation on Gentee...

Comment: Use this: http://www.onlinecompiler.net/ it is very good. You just enter the code and download the exe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can cross-compile from another platform, e.g. using [MinGW on another OS such as Linux or Mac OS X](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LinuxCrossMinGW), but ultimately you need a compiler *somewhere*.

If you don't actually need a .EXE *per se*, but just want to compile and run some C code without having to install a compiler, e.g. for educational/experimental purposes, then there are very useful sites such as [codepad.org](http://codepad.org) and [ideone.com](http://ideone.com) which provide this capability for C and a number of other languages.

Answer (score 4):

If you are really crazy it is possible. You would need an hexadecimal editor and assembly knowledge. Then you could play the "human compiler" game, transforming C into assembly and putting the opcodes in the hex editor. To learn something it might be useful but in the general case really use a compiler!

Comment: yaa @Jdehaan you are right you need to have assembly knowledge  to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

You need a C compiler and linker. Your friend is confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio Express, too.

Since Visual Studio 2003, Microsoft doesn't provide pure command line compiler. The compiler is shipped with an IDE now.

Answer (score 0):

with what jokester said, that will just change the way it opens, rather than converting the file itself, so when you try and open it, you will just get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I use the codeblocks compiler for my C code, and with that, it does it for you, just go into the project folder of the project you just made, then go into the bin folder, then go into the debug folder, and there is a program in there, which is your program and it is a .exe file

Hope i may have helped someone

Answer (score -1):

There is no way, I would say. By definition

Compiler is responsible for

1. Checking error in your code

   Convert the error free code into an object file

Linker is responsbile for converting the object file into an executable. In the case of Windows, it is a .exe file.

Answer (score -1):

u just use Turbo C++ it will automatically make a .exe file. You can find it under "TurboC++\Disk\TurboC3\BIN" hope this hepled